# Shell include space and asterisk

Tags: shell, space

Defind string array in shell script below. I want show the sql nomal, what should I do?

```
a=("select * from t1;"
"select * from t2;"
"select  from t3;")

echo ${#a[@]}"--------"

for var1 in ${a[@]};do
    echo  "${var1}"
done
```

Comment: `${a[@]}` -> `"${a[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

This would do it for you

```
a=( 'select * from t1;'
    'select * from t2;'
    'select * from t3;' )


for query in "${a[@]}"; do
  echo "$query"
done
```

RESULT

```
$ sh SO.sh 
select * from t1;
select * from t2;
select * from t3;
$
```